# $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is irrational

Tags: radicals, irrational-numbers

How to prove $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is irrational?

I know this question was asked many time before but I can't understand the way the people explained the question so is it possible for someone to re-explain this question but with easy wording so I can understand better.

Comment: Ever seen http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/q1.html ? That is similar only using a square root instead of a cube and 2 instead of 5 but the proof idea would probably be the same.

Comment: The killer app would be the rational root theorem ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly the same as proving $\sqrt2 $ is irrational.

Suppose $5 = ({\frac a b})^3$ where $a, b$ are integers and $gcd(a,b) = 1)$ [i.e. the fraction is in lowest terms].

The $5b^3 = a^3$ so 5 divides $a^3$ but as 5 is prime (indivisible) it follows 5 divides $a$.  So $a = 5a'$ for some integer $a'$.

So $5b^3 = (5a')^3 = 125a'^3$ so $b^3 = 25a'^3$.

So $25$ divides $b^3$.  So $5$ divides $b^3$.  But as 5 is prime (indivisible) it follows that 5 divides $b$.

So you have $5$ divides $a$  *AND* we have $5$ divides $b$.  But that contradicts gcd(a, b) = 1 and that the fraction is in lowest terms.

We must conclude such a fraction is impossible and $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is irrational.